# How can I get automatically numbered headings in confluence?

Tags: javascript, wiki, confluence

Currently it is not possible in confluence to have the headings of the document structure numbered automatically. I am aware that there are (paid) 3rd party plugins available.

How can I achieve continuous numbered headings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

Create a bookmark for the following javascript and click it in edit mode in confluence to renumber your headings.

```js
javascript:(function()%7Bfunction%20addIndex()%20%7Bvar%20indices%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3BjQuery(%22.ak-editor-content-area%20.ProseMirror%22).find(%22h1%2Ch2%2Ch3%2Ch4%2Ch5%2Ch6%22).each(function(i%2Ce)%20%7Bvar%20hIndex%20%3D%20parseInt(this.nodeName.substring(1))%20-%201%3Bif%20(indices.length%20-%201%20%3E%20hIndex)%20%7Bindices%3D%20indices.slice(0%2C%20hIndex%20%2B%201%20)%3B%7Dif%20(indices%5BhIndex%5D%20%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7Bindices%5BhIndex%5D%20%3D%200%3B%7Dindices%5BhIndex%5D%2B%2B%3BjQuery(this).html(indices.join(%22.%22)%2B%22.%20%22%20%2B%20removeNo(jQuery(this).html()))%3B%7D)%3B%7Dfunction%20removeNo(str)%20%7Blet%20newstr%20%3D%20str.trim()%3Bnewstr%20%3D%20newstr.replace(%2F%5B%5Cu00A0%5Cu1680%E2%80%8B%5Cu180e%5Cu2000-%5Cu2009%5Cu200a%E2%80%8B%5Cu200b%E2%80%8B%5Cu202f%5Cu205f%E2%80%8B%5Cu3000%5D%2Fg%2C'%20')%3Bif(IsNumeric(newstr.substring(0%2Cnewstr.indexOf('%20'))))%7Breturn%20newstr.substring(newstr.indexOf('%20')%2B1).trim()%3B%7Dreturn%20newstr%3B%7Dfunction%20IsNumeric(num)%20%7Bnum%20%3D%20num.split('.').join(%22%22)%3Breturn%20(num%20%3E%3D0%20%7C%7C%20num%20%3C%200)%3B%7DaddIndex()%7D)()
```

### Result

[image: initial structure]
[image: numbered structure]

### How to use

After changes to the structure have been made, clicking the bookmarked javascript renumbers the document.

Limitations are that it only provides n.n.n. numbering, but for many cases that's sufficient. The script can also be customized as required.

### Background, explanation and disclosure

I tried this [TaperMonkey script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/381252-confluence-auto-numbered-headings) that apparently resulted from [this post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Is-it-possible-to-add-numbering-to-headings-in-Confluence/qaq-p/315517#M87046), but it didn't work as is. So I took its [source code](https://gist.github.com/elahd/28f64feddd9ece56f4f0566d195d0cbd) and stripped it of the integration code, old version compatibility and made some minor adjustments to get this:

```js
function addIndex() {
        var indices = [];

            jQuery(".ak-editor-content-area .ProseMirror").find("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(function(i,e) {
                var hIndex = parseInt(this.nodeName.substring(1)) - 1;
                if (indices.length - 1 > hIndex) {
                    indices= indices.slice(0, hIndex + 1 );
                }
                if (indices[hIndex] == undefined) {
                    indices[hIndex] = 0;
                }
                indices[hIndex]++;
                jQuery(this).html(indices.join(".")+". " + removeNo(jQuery(this).html()));
            });
    }

    function removeNo(str) {
        let newstr = str.trim();
        newstr = newstr.replace(/[\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a​\u200b​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]/g,' ');
        if(IsNumeric(newstr.substring(0,newstr.indexOf(' ')))){
            return newstr.substring(newstr.indexOf(' ')+1).trim();
        }
        return newstr;
    }

    function IsNumeric(num) {
        num = num.split('.').join("");
        return (num >=0 || num < 0);
    }
    
addIndex();
```

(I'm not a JavaScript developer, I'm sure it can be written nicer/better)

Then I used [bookmarklet](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) to convert it into the javascript bookmark at the top, which can be clicked to trigger the functionality.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'

Comment: It needs to be a bookmark. If you want to execute the javascript directly, copy the listing below.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Created a bookmark with Firefox 119 on Linux, pasted the javascript bookmark code. Clicked this bookmark in Confluence 8.5.2 page edit mode. Nothing happened. Huh? Same result with Chrome 108.
The javascript code generated with the built-in "Share in Confluence" macro works, btw.

Comment: The code may no longer match with the attributes a current confluence generates. Sorry if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the bookmarklet approach, I have created a Chrome Extension that will add this functionality in a Context Menu and inject the script in the page.
See https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2024/03/crx-confluence-numbered-headings.html and the source code available in GitHub https://github.com/tdalon/confluence_crx

This avoids the trouble to setup the bookmarklets and make the functionality also better accessible.
Besides the Chrome Extension has some other nice functionalities like quick combined search by labels.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by: https://2ality.com/2012/01/numbering-headingshtml.html

Here is a CSS you can apply in Confluence look&feel/stylesheet for auto numbering.

```
.wiki-content h1 {
  counter-increment: h1counter;
  counter-reset: h2counter;
}
.wiki-content h1::before {
  content: counter(h1counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}
.wiki-content h2 {
  counter-increment: h2counter;
  counter-reset: h3counter;
}
.wiki-content h2::before {
  content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}
.wiki-content h3 {
  counter-increment: h3counter;
  counter-reset: h4counter;
}
.wiki-content h3::before {
  content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}
.wiki-content h4 {
  counter-increment: h4counter;
}
.wiki-content h4::before {
  content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) "." counter(h4counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";    }
```

With this, you can make the numbering visible in TOC:

```
.toc-macro.hidden-outline span.toc-outline {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This solution would be global for all users, right? I prefer to have the possibility to make the choice of numbering or not user-based.